# rsync copy only specific files from specific subfolders, without creating empty folders

Tags: rsync

Imagine a file structure like this:

```
test
├── a
│   ├── 0
│   │   ├── file0.rtf
│   │   ├── file0.txt
│   │   ├── file1.rtf
│   │   ├── file1.txt
│   │   ├── file2.rtf
│   │   └── file2.txt
│   ├── 1
│   │   ├── file0.rtf
│   │   ├── file0.txt
│   │   ├── file1.rtf
│   │   ├── file1.txt
│   │   ├── file2.rtf
│   │   └── file2.txt
│   ├── 2
│   │   ├── file0.rtf
│   │   ├── file0.txt
│   │   ├── file1.rtf
│   │   ├── file1.txt
│   │   ├── file2.rtf
│   │   └── file2.txt
│   └── 3
│       ├── file0.rtf
│       ├── file0.txt
│       ├── file1.rtf
│       ├── file1.txt
│       ├── file2.rtf
│       └── file2.txt
└── b
    ├── 0
    │   ├── file0.rtf
    │   ├── file0.txt
    │   ├── file1.rtf
    │   ├── file1.txt
    │   ├── file2.rtf
    │   └── file2.txt
    ├── 1
    │   ├── file0.rtf
    │   ├── file0.txt
    │   ├── file1.rtf
    │   ├── file1.txt
    │   ├── file2.rtf
    │   └── file2.txt
    ├── 2
    │   ├── file0.rtf
    │   ├── file0.txt
    │   ├── file1.rtf
    │   ├── file1.txt
    │   ├── file2.rtf
    │   └── file2.txt
    └── 3
        ├── file0.rtf
        ├── file0.txt
        ├── file1.rtf
        ├── file1.txt
        ├── file2.rtf
        └── file2.txt
```

Where I do *not know* the real names of `a` and `b`. Nevertheless, I want to copy all `*.txt` files from subfolders of `a` and `b` (however they are named) if they are in the subfolder `0`.

It kind of works if I am using

```
rsync -avz --include=*/ --include='*/0/*.txt' --exclude=* test/ test2/
```

However, rsync creates empty folders `1`, `2`, `3`, which I would like to avoid. How do I do this?

Output from the `rsync` command above:

```
sending incremental file list
a/
a/0/
a/0/file0.txt
a/0/file1.txt
a/0/file2.txt
a/1/
a/2/
a/3/
b/
b/0/
b/0/file0.txt
b/0/file1.txt
b/0/file2.txt
b/1/
b/2/
b/3/
```

I want

```
sending incremental file list
a/
a/0/
a/0/file0.txt
a/0/file1.txt
a/0/file2.txt
b/
b/0/
b/0/file0.txt
b/0/file1.txt
b/0/file2.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the answer is simple. Just adding the `--prune-empty-dirs` flag does the trick.

```
rsync -avz --include=*/ --include='*/0/*.txt' --exclude=* --prune-empty-dirs test1/ test2/
```

That is what I wanted.